# How to pass a VBScript-generated argument to an already-open batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, file-io, vbscript

I have written a batch file that passes two arguments to a VBScript file, like so:

```
call "Command_case.vbs" "%COMMAND%" "%PARAM%"
```

Now, in my VBScript I have a switch (well, select case) statement that checks what the `%COMMAND%` is and I would like to return arguments to the (still open) batch file, here is my VBScript:

```
Select Case WScript.Arguments(0)
Case "decrypt"

Case "encrypt"

Case "open"

Case "archive"

Case "expand"

Case else
    'in here I would like to return an argument to the batch of "null", or something along those lines.
End Select
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the errorlevel using `wscript.Quit(Numeric_Value)`
Where Numeric_Value is a value between -999999999 and 999999999

```
Select Case WScript.Arguments(0)
Case "decrypt"

Case "encrypt"

Case "open"

Case "archive"

Case "expand"

Case else
    wscript.Quit(2)
End Select
```

And in your batch :

```
call "Command_case.vbs" "%COMMAND%" "%PARAM%"
if %errorlevle% equ 2 echo ELSE
```